# In Elipse, python Shared Object file illegible

Tags: numpy, shared-libraries, cpython

Please consider the following code, which compiles and runs as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x*13)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('A single plot')
```

In Eclipse, when I hover the mouse over the sin function it directs me to the following 'Shared Object' file

```
_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

However, when I open the file in a separate tab the file is illegible. What would people recommend to be able to see the contents of the file , like *.py core files where there are many useful examples ? Would you want to do that anyway ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's compiled code.  It's not meant to be human readable.  In a development repository you may find the corresponding `c` source code, but that takes a lot digging.

Comment: But functions like `np.sin` do have documentation ('docs'). https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html

Comment: ......Thank you......